# how to stop an update panel from refreshing when the same updatepanel does the postback

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an update panel with a linkbutton inside of it. The updatepanel has its updatemode set to conditional. From what I understand, regardless if the updatemode is set to conditional, it will refresh the panel, if something inside of it initiates the postback. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the linkbutton, if not doing an async update?

Comment: It would be an async postback, however it would update another updatepanel. The updatepanel with the linkbutton is dynamically generated, and not rebuilt everytime the page is created, hence it disappears when the linkbutton is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the content you want to avoid the postback outside of the updatepanel, as far as I know.  I haven't heard of another alternative, unless you manually update the UI via JavaScript and AJAX web services.

If you can, don't know the situation, you could consider having the link as a client-side link, and have it do whatever you need to do... as in:

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doThis();">Do This</a>

What do you need to do?

Comment: I think the only option is to do it through javascript then, I think that should work. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set ChildrenAsTriggers="false" on the update panel? Update mode must be conditional then, but it won't update if I understand things correctly.

EDIT: Sorry, just realized it's an old thread :(